# Spring ApplicationContext creation

Tags: java, spring

I was looking at how internally, Spring is creating singelton classes.

**Expectation:**

1. Spring will iterate through all the relevant classes (mentioned via XML)
2. Create a dependency graph for classes
3. And will create instances as part of traversing the above tree.

**Observations:**

1. Spring iterated through all the relevant classes (mentioned via XML)
2. Create a map of className vs BeanInfo (Metadata about class)
3. Traverse through all the classes one by one and checked its constructor. If the constructor argument are not yet created, it creates them first, and then finally created the class, and added it in the sigelton objects list. (org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext#finishBeanFactoryInitialization)

**Code:**

```
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
```

**Question:**

Why Spring doesn't create graph of classes, in the first iteration for faster initialisation? Please let me know, if I have missed something while reading/debugging Spring code.

Comment: Why do you think creating a graph will be faster?

Comment: As per my understanding, say due to graph creation - 2 disjoint trees structure got created (Simplest scenario):

Pros: (Can speed processing)
1. We can use parallelisation for instantiating both the trees. 
2. Creation of singelton nodes from down to up. So, very rare chance that while creating a node we will ever find any constructor class which has not been created.


Cons: (Memory)
For maintaining DAG, memory can be an issue.

Comment: 1. Well, OK, that's theoretically possible. but nothing prohibits parallel creation without a graph.

Comment: 2. Don't see how this is relevant. You effectively traverse the while graph one way or another, and beans are not created second time. So why would it matter in which order they are created?

Comment: Memory for maintaining a DAG for typicaly a few dozen beans is not really worth mentioning.

Comment: I'd be rather interested in how Spring detects cycles.